# Replacement for discontinued Schwalbe Tyrago

Tags: tire

Schwalbe appear to have discontinued their Tyrago range of tyres from what I can tell.

The rear tyre on my Boardman CX Comp needs replacing as it's showing wear and has little tread left for grip. **What supersedes it as the closest direct replacement** or a good alternative? (I cycle on-and-off road, nothing too serious; the Tyrago seemed to cope well unless it was particularly muddy up hill.)

Comment: There is quite a range of cyclocross to gravel bike tyres to chose from. Take a look at the websites of online retailers. Giving buying recommendations is not practised on this site.

Comment: I understand that @Carel, I've clarified I'm simply after knowing what the closest, direct replacement supersedes it. Not a recommendation as such.

Comment: @Mat Sorry but that's still a recommendation, just with a slightly unusual criterion, and it's still off-topic for all the same reasons: answers will go out of date, availability varies regionally, and the question is tied to your personal preferences in a tyre.

Comment: I don't know Tyrago, but it looks very much like the old pattern of Schwalbe Land Cruiser tyres. Perhaps they were renamed for the UK market? Besides, Land Cruisers are not really good tyres. With the same compound and puncture guard the Tyrago are likely no better. You might switch to a faster tyre with slightly worse puncture protection (cf @Gregory Leo answer), or to a really well protected tyre with similar rolling resistance when you look around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean a CX tyre having similar tread to your Tyrago? Do you mean performance-wise? Same brand? Why don't you just buy a new tyre of same brand and model (Tyrago supersedes Tyrago)?

The question's a bit vague. Most CX tires produced recently are pretty much well-performing and supersedes Tyrago (or even better than it), though it depends on its specializations.

Anyways, I'll hand out some examples of CX tires with similar, angled treads/knobbles: (might give you insight on what you want)

Michelin Protek Cross - very fast rolling (road) but slippy in muddy conditions.

[image]

Michelin Cyclocross Mud 2 - fast rolling (road), more traction, a bit mud-clearing
[image]

Bontrager CX0 - pretty fast rolling (road), okay traction, not that mud-clearing, side knobs for cornering
[image]

Maxxis Mud Wrestler - okay rolling (road), nice traction, very mud-clearing
[image]

Continental Cyclo X King - meh rolling (road), mud-biting traction, mud-clearing
[image]

Hope you can sort that thing out. I myself use something like the Bontrager CX0 as I both go on long road tours and off-road sessions.

Comment: Isn’t the Tyrago more like a touring tire with some tread? I think it’s most similar to a Schwalbe Marathon (less tread) or a Schwalbe Smart Sam (more tread) or Schwalbe CX Comp.

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure about the type of tyre Tyrago is designed for but it's similar to the Maxxis Mud Wrestler but with wider knobs (not taller) like the Michelin Protek Cross and if it's specc'd to a CX bike (together with OP's okay reviews), then it's probably decent enough.

I'm showing these examples to OP to enlighten him on what type of CX tyre to choose since he only vaguely wants a tyre 'equal or better' than Tyrago.

Comment: The Tyrago is a wire beaded, puncture protected touring tyre with a hard wearing compound. It seems rather similar to Schwalbe Land Cruiser. That is very much unlike these fast, and light folding tyres you listed. It is a good overview still and might be of use if the OP has less need for puncture protection and prefers to upgrade to a faster tyre.

Comment: Thanks. Unless I'm mistaken the Tyrago range appears to be discontinued (so I can't replace like for like, hence the question). It sounds like there's not a direct replacement.